Finding stress associated to a free energy
I am trying to find the stress tensor associated to the following free energy
$F = \int dV [ a |\nabla L|^2 + b |\nabla^2 L|^2]$
Where L is the heigh of the fluid interface, and is only a function of $x$.
I went through the literature and found that the stress $\sigma_{ij}$ can be found by defining the work done as
$\delta F = \int \sigma_{ij} \nabla_i \delta x_j$.
In this paper, the stress has been found from the free energy for a system with scaler order parameter (see Eq.s 13-16). However, those equations are only valid for the conserved order parameter $\phi$.
Could anyone help me with finding the stress for my system?
